# Использование двух копий одном dll в проекте

Tags: qt, dll

Можно ли использовать несколько копий одной dll в одном проекте? Я хочу написать два класса, каждый из которых будет использовать свою копию данной dll. Я так понимаю, ничто не мешает подключить к .pro две одинаковых dll из разных директорий, но ведь имя .h файла менять нельзя, как в таком случае понять какая из них к какому .cpp файлу заикнлюжена?

Comment: Проекту вообще поперек на dll. Такого типа библиотеки загружаются во время выполнения программы и они не будут загружены дважды, если их имена одинаковы.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, то есть вариантов использовать разные копии dll не существует?

Comment: Существует: используйте разные имена файлов. Только зачем оно вам? Код один и тот же, какой смысл загружать его дважды?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, какой именно файл нужно переименовать? dll,.h или .lib? Суть в том, что данная библиотека используется для взаимодействия с прибором и внутри она как-то залочена на одновременное подключение только одного прибора. Грубо говоря, после использование функции connectDevice(), второй раз для другого прибора её использовать нельзя.

Comment: *.dll надо переименовать. Только наверняка не получится, если авторы не заморочились на поддержку нескольких экземпляров оборудования при разработке.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, получается, я запускал две копии программы, осуществляющей подключение и оно успешно производилось, но мне нужно в одной копии программы два одновременно. прошу прощения, не очень вас понял. библиотека состоит из трех файлов dll,.h и .lib, если я поменяю название .dll , и подключу, условно говоря, devicelib.dll и devicelib2.dll, то .h файлы то у них всё равно одноименные, как тогда понять какой куда иклюдить?

Comment: А *.h к dll имеет отношение опосредованное, там объявлены прототипы функций. Подозреваю, что вам нужно загружать разные dll через LoadLibrary, получать нужные функции и их дергать.